# Contradiction in the Taz between early Shavuos and early Shemini Atzeres

Tags: yom-tov, shavuos, contradiction, shmini-atzeres

In his disagreement with the Maharshal's ruling not to start Shemini Atzeres early, the [Taz](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.668.1?p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.668.1)'s first objection is a long poetic rendition about why we shouldn't forbid something that isn't mentioned in the Gemara or earlier Poskim.

On Shavuos, not only does the [Taz](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.494.1?p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.494.1) accept the Shelah's ruling not to make kiddush early, but he extends it to not davening maariv early.  As far as I know, the whole issue isn't mentioned by anyone earlier than the Shelah, and maariv isn't mentioned by anyone earlier than the Taz.

Why is the Taz inconsistent between these two very similar cases?

---

(I'm asking only about the Taz's objection to forbidding something that was not mentioned in earlier sources.  His further objections to the Maharshal are based on his opinion that can be summarized as "strong tosefes".  This is conceptually consistent with his strict ruling on Shavuos once you accept the Shelah's drasha of תמימות.  I don't think this point is essential to the question, but can elaborate if necessary.)

Comment: I don't see contradiction. Temimot is an exception and there is no possibility to add from the chol to kodesh.

Comment: @kouty a few achronim say that, but most say that you still have to do tosefes, just not kiddush.  The contradiction is that the Shelah's drasha originated with him and doesn't come from the Gemara or Poskim - exactly the same as the Maharshal's ruling that the Taz rejects for this reason.  Conceptually his two positions make a lot of sense together, but not in his attitude to chiddushim not found in Chazal.

Comment: No one actually believes that everything must be in Shas. By ShAtz the Taz is implicitly saying that there isn't enough basis to defend a practice that isn't mentioned in Shas. But if there's a strong enough argument he'd accept it, as evidently happened for shavuot

Comment: @DoubleAA that's reasonable in logic, but his tone makes the contrast even stronger.  (a) "There's no way this is possible (לפענ"ד)!! How can you make people fast until the night??  And even if you did there's no way Chazal would have been silent about it!!"  (b) "We daven maariv late on Shavuos because תמימות" with no further elaboration.

Comment: As you said he's poetic. That means he's trying to make a point. Sometimes people feel a need to make a point and sometimes they don't. Whatever.

Comment: To more directly address your case, I'm not sure he's that insistent on late shavuot and not just that it's a good thing and that's what we do. Also erev shavuot isn't a holiday and no one is banning you from celebrating it or eating on it, not that there's anyone who cares about its honor to defend it were we to do that. To declare a fast on hoshana rabba and force you to not fulfill sukkah deorayta is a Big Deal(TM).

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the first sentence of your second comment is the answer.  The Taz wouldn't agree with your distinction between erev shavuot and hoshana rabba because he says that starting Yom Tov removes the previous day.